# Rails undefined method error only in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, heroku

I'm building an app similar to hackernews to learn Rails. Everything is working in development, but when I deploy on heroku I get the following error:

```
Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
2013-07-12T23:07:52.084981+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method       `username' for nil:NilClass):
2013-07-12T23:07:52.082828+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 122ms
2013-07-12T23:07:52.084981+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:     <%= pluralize(article.votes.count, 'vote') %>
2013-07-12T23:07:52.084981+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:   </div>
2013-07-12T23:07:52.084981+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:     by <%= link_to article.user.username, profile_path(user_id: article.user.id) %>
2013-07-12T23:07:52.084981+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:     <%= time_ago_in_words(article.created_at) %> ago |
2013-07-12T23:07:52.084981+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:   </div>
```

Here's my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true

  has_many :votes
  has_many :articles
  has_many :comments

  def already_voted_on?(id)
    self.votes.where(votable_id: id).count > 0
  end
end
```

And here's my index view (line 10 is throwing the error). For some reason it's not recognizing a user's "username" attribute even though it works in development:

```
<div class="articles">
  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <div class="title">
    <%= link_to image_tag('votearrow.gif'), votes_path(votable_id: article.id, value: 1, votable_type: "Article"), method: :post %>
    <%= link_to article.title, article.url %>
    <%= image_tag("http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain_url=" + article.url) %>
  </div>
  <div class="submitted-by">
    <%= pluralize(article.votes.count, 'vote') %>
by <%= link_to article.user.username, profile_path(user_id: article.user.id) %>
    <%= time_ago_in_words(article.created_at) %> ago |
   </div>
   <div class="comments">
     <%= link_to pluralize((article.comments.count), 'comment'), article_path(id: article.id) %>
  </div>
      <br><br>
      <% end %>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Username is not a devise's field, so maybe you forgot to run your migrations in production environment?

Comment: I ran 'heroku run rake db:migrate' but it still doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

The problem was heroku wasn't updating my latest migration (AddUserIdToArticles). I fixed the problem by deleting the column in the database, adding it again, and running heroku restart.